# Swagger-codegen flask generated server locally doesn't works

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, swagger, openapi

I have generated a simple API server example using swaggerhub, and downloaded python-flask generated server locally.

Unfortunately, it seems to not work at all. Every time I try to access the indicated url, that is

http://localhost:8080/data/2.5//ui/

it returns me a 404 error.

I've tried all the solutions reported on:

[Python connexion not displaying Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246811/python-connexion-not-displaying-swagger-ui/50286658)

but with no success. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple detail that made all work: after executing `pip install 'connexion[swagger-ui]'` and `pip install pathlib swagger_ui_bundle` (though I am not sure the last is strictly needed...), the server worked only with an *invalidate cache and restart* command on PyCharm.