# Connexion not serving up Swagger UI

Tags: api, flask, swagger, openapi, connexion

I'm trying to build a simple API with Swagger/Flask/Connexion, however the example on their GitHub does not work, even after installing connexion[swagger-ui] as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246811/python-connexion-not-displaying-swagger-ui)

```
pip3 install 'connexion[swagger-ui]'
```

Here is my helloworld-api.yaml:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"

info:
  title: Hello World
  version: "1.0"
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:9090/swagger

paths:
  /greeting:
    get:
      summary: Generate greeting
      description: Generates a greeting message.
      operationId: hello.get_greeting
      responses:
        200:
          description: greeting response
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: "hello dave!"
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: name
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: "dave"
          description: Name of the person to greet.
```

and my hello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import connexion


def get_greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return f'Hello {name}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir='openapi/')
    app.add_api('helloworld-api.yaml', arguments={'title': 'Hello World Example'})
    app.run(port=8080)
```

hello.py is in the root directory and helloworld-api.yaml is in a folder called openapi/.  Navigating to a 0.0.0.0:8080/swagger in a browser returns this:

```
{
  "detail": "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
  "status": 404,
  "title": "Not Found",
  "type": "about:blank"
}
```

Same goes for the get method I've specified. Any ideas? I've been banging my head against a brick wall over this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong patch , to access Swagger UI you must access `{base_path}/ui/` in your case `0.0.0.0:8080/ui/`

You can check the docs https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#the-swagger-ui-console